# General way of filtering by IDs with DRF

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

Is there a generic way that I can filter by an array of IDs when using DRF?
For example, if I wanted to return all images with the following IDs, I would do this:

`/images/?ids=1,2,3,4`

My current implementation is to do the following:

```
# filter
class ProjectImageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    """
    Filter on existing fields, or defined query_params with
    associated functions
    """
    ids = django_filters.MethodFilter(action='id_list')

    def id_list(self, queryset, value):
        """
        Filter by IDs by passing in a query param of this structure
            `?ids=265,263`
        """
        id_list = value.split(',')
        return queryset.filter(id__in=id_list)

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectImage
        fields = ['ids',]


# viewset
class Images(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Images associated with a project
    """
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    queryset = ProjectImage.objects.all()
    filter_class = ProjectImageFilter
```

However, in this case `ProjectImageFilter` requires a model to be specified ( `ProjectImage`). Is there a way that I can just generally define this filter so I can use it on multiple ViewSets with different models?

Comment: Not a solution, however for the same reasons I have added additional fields to my model to store the file name and even file keywords. That way I can easily search through my files by name and keyword.

Answer (score 1):

One solution without `django-filters` is to just `super()` override `get_queryset`. Here is an example:

```
class MyViewSet(view.ViewSet):

    # your code

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(MyViewSet, self).get_queryset()

        ids = self.request.query_params.get('ids', None)
        if ids:
            ids_list = ids.split(',')
            queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=ids_list)

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

The library `django-filter` has support for this using `BaseInFilter`, in conjunction with DRF.

From [their docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter):

```
class NumberRangeFilter(BaseRangeFilter, NumberFilter):
    pass

class F(FilterSet):
    id__range = NumberRangeFilter(field_name='id', lookup_expr='range')

    class Meta:
        model = User

User.objects.create(username='alex')
User.objects.create(username='jacob')
User.objects.create(username='aaron')
User.objects.create(username='carl')

# Range: User with IDs between 1 and 3.
f = F({'id__range': '1,3'})
assert len(f.qs) == 3
```